# Limiting the max size of a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to limit the maximum size of a `HashMap` to take metrics on a variety of hashing algorithms that I'm implementing. I looked at the loadfactor in one of `HashMap`'s overloaded constructors.

```
HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)
```

I tried setting the loadFactor to 0.0f in the constructor (meaning that I don't want the HashMap to grow in size EVER) but `javac` calls this invalid:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal load factor: 0.0
        at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:177)
        at hashtables.CustomHash.<init>(Main.java:20)
        at hashtables.Main.main(Main.java:70) Java Result: 1
```

Is there another way to limit the size of `HashMap` so it doesn't grow ever?

Comment: What should happen when the Map is full and you try to insert another element?

Comment: Just as an FYI, hash tables need to compress their keyspace because you cannot reserve 2^31 * 4 bytes of memory space to hold the value for every possible key. Therefore, hash tables usually truncate the hash and use linked lists for collisions. The loadFactor rougly indicates the maximum size of the linked before the table starts using more bits of the hash. Therefore, 0 length linked lists doesnt make sense: you cant store anything in it.

Comment: Load factor says when to increase the data structure size. Initial size(i) and Load factor(x) means, we increase size when we have i*x elements. if x = 0, it is like asking Java to increase data structure size whenever it has 0 elements.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sometimes simpler is better.

```
public class InstrumentedHashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private Map<K, V> map;

    public InstrumentedHashMap() {
        map = new HashMap<K, V>();
    }

    public boolean put(K key, V value) {
        if (map.size() >= MAX && !map.containsKey(key)) {
             return false;
        } else {
             map.put(key, value);
             return true;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This answer limits the _maximum_ size of your Map. See Margus' answer for a simpler Map that prevents putting _or removing_ entries.

Comment: @mattburns, Isn't that the question? Or the question has been rephrased after your comment?

Comment: @sriman , well, yeah, that matches the question title, but not the detailed question description. OP wanted it to never grow ever (Eg, be immutable). But 10 years on, people reading this will probably only be here because they searched for limiting the max capacity of hashmaps... Meh

Comment: You can extend AbstractMap or HashMap to avoid having to reimplement the entire Map interface.

Answer (score 147):

You could create a new class like this to limit the size of a HashMap:

```
public class MaxSizeHashMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
    private final int maxSize;

    public MaxSizeHashMap(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > maxSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if I understand correctly, this way when you insert a new element, it just removes the eldest element from the map, and inserts the new one instead, thus limiting the size to `maxSize`. It's not that it doesn't let you add new elements.

Answer (score 6):

> I tried setting the loadFactor to 0.0f in the constructor (meaning that I don't want the HashMap to grow in size EVER) but `javac` calls this invalid

A `loadFactor` of `1.0f` means "don't grow until the HashMap is 100% full". A `loadFactor` of `0.0f` would mean "grow exponentially" if it were accepted, which is why it's not.

From the [HashMap docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> The *capacity* is the number of buckets in the hash table, and the initial capacity is simply the capacity at the time the hash table is created. The *load factor* is a measure of how full the hash table is allowed to get before its capacity is automatically increased. When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is *rehashed* (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table has approximately twice the number of buckets.

Example: A HashMap initialized with default settings has a capacity of 16 and a load factor of `0.75f`. `Capacity * load factor = 16 * 0.75 = 12`. So adding the 13th item to the HashMap will cause it to grow to (approximately) 32 buckets.

Invalid example: A HashMap initialized with a capacity of 16 and a load factor of `0.0f`. `Capacity * load factor = 16 * 0 = 0`. So *every attempt* to add an item would trigger a rehash and doubling of size, until you ran out of memory.

What you originally wanted:

> If the initial capacity is greater than the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash operations will ever occur.

If you create a HashMap with a capacity M > N, a load factor of 1, and add N items, it will not grow.

```
Map<KeyType, ValueType> nonGrowingHashMap = new HashMap<>(MAXIMUM_MAP_SIZE, 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution is usually the best, so use [unmodifiable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29) or [Immutable](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) hashmap.

If you can not change amount of elements, then the size will be fixed - problem solved.

Comment: Not always better as HashMaps are used most often when there is a large amount of data to be hadled in memory. Memory consumption can become an issue when using Immutable hashmaps

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Cache {
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> Cache = null;
    private final int cacheSize;  
    private ReadWriteLock readWriteLock=null;
    public Cache(LinkedHashMap<String, String> psCacheMap, int size) {
        this.Cache = psCacheMap;
        cacheSize = size;
        readWriteLock=new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    }

    public void put(String sql, String pstmt) throws SQLException{
        if(Cache.size() >= cacheSize && cacheSize > 0){
            String oldStmt=null;
            String oldSql = Cache.keySet().iterator().next();
            oldStmt = remove(oldSql);
            oldStmt.inCache(false);
            oldStmt.close();

        }
        Cache.put(sql, pstmt);
    }

    public String get(String sql){
        Lock readLock=readWriteLock.readLock();
        try{
            readLock.lock();
            return Cache.get(sql);
        }finally{
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean containsKey(String sql){
        Lock readLock=readWriteLock.readLock();
        try{
            readLock.lock();
            return Cache.containsKey(sql);
        }finally{
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public String remove(String key){
        Lock writeLock=readWriteLock.writeLock();
        try{
            writeLock.lock();
            return Cache.remove(key);
        }finally{
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getCache() {
        return Cache;
    }

    public void setCache(
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> Cache) {
        this.Cache = Cache;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `put` in the HashMap class is the one in charge of adding the elements into the HashMap and it does it by calling a method named addEntry which code is as follows:

```
   void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
        Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
        table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
        if (size++ >= threshold)
            resize(2 * table.length);
    }
```

As you can see in this method is where the HashMap is resized if the threshold has been exceeded, so I would try extending the class HashMap and writing my own methods for `put` and `addEntry` in order to remove the resizing. Something like:

```
package java.util;

public class MyHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap {


    private V myPutForNullKey(V value) {
        for (Entry<K, V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
            if (e.key == null) {
                V oldValue = e.value;
                e.value = value;
                e.recordAccess(this);
                return oldValue;
            }
        }
        modCount++;
        myAddEntry(0, null, value, 0);
        return null;
    }

    public V myPut(K key, V value) {
        if (key == null)
            return myPutForNullKey(value);
        if (size < table.length) { 
            int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
            int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
            for (Entry<K, V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
                Object k;
                if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
                    V oldValue = e.value;
                    e.value = value;
                    e.recordAccess(this);
                    return oldValue;
                }
            }

            modCount++;
            myAddEntry(hash, key, value, i);
        }
        return null;
    }

    void myAddEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
        Entry<K, V> e = table[bucketIndex];
        table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K, V>(hash, key, value, e);
        size++;
    }
}
```

You would need to write your own methods since `put` and `addEntry` cannot be overriding and you would also need to do the same for `putForNullKey` since it is called inside `put`. A validation in `put` is required to verify that we are not trying to put an object if the table is full.