# Measure Spring RestTemplate HTTP request time

Tags: java, performance, web-services, spring, http

I want to measure the time of the HTTP GET request of a `RestTemplate.getForObject` call without the the time needed for parsing the response. So just the time the remote HTTP call needs. I already tried setting a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` but I dont think this is the right way to do it as the time seems to be wrong:

```
public class PerfRequestSyncInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
        ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    ClientHttpResponse resp = execution.execute(request, body);

    log.debug("remote request time: "
            + ((System.nanoTime() - start) * Math.pow(10, -9)));
    return resp;
  }
}
```

Call:

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
interceptors.add(new PerfRequestSyncInterceptor());
rest.setInterceptors(interceptors);

Response inob = rest.getForObject(xmlURL, Response.class);
```

How can I measure the time of a RestTemplate HTTP request?

Comment: I had the same problem. You need to make a method call on the response object to block execution until the response is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AOP and the built in PerformanceMonitorInterceptor of Spring. You need to correctly define which methods of which calss you want to intercept then you can measure. You can configure it something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">
    <bean id="springMonitoredService"
        class="com.myorg.service.springmon.MyServiceSpringImpl"/>


    <bean id="springMonitoringAspectInterceptor"        
class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor">
        <property name="loggerName"     
                value="com.myorg.SPRING_MONITOR"/>      
    </bean>


    <aop:config>
            <aop:pointcut id="springMonitoringPointcut"
                   expression="execution(* java.net.HttpURLConnection.connect(..))"/>




                <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="springMonitoringPointcut" 
            advice-ref="springMonitoringAspectInterceptor"/>      
    </aop:config>

</beans>
```

Comment: And which method should I configure for measurement?

Comment: Internally RestTemplate uses java.net.HttpURLConnection you will need to measure the connect() method. Additionally you can try the getDoOutput() method too

Comment: May I ask you to update your answer to point to this methods?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. But if I change the expression to a public method of my class that uses rest template, it works. Is my version of template not using HttpURLConnection?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stopwatch to do that.

```
public class PerfRequestSyncInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PerfRequestSyncInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest hr, byte[] bytes, ClientHttpRequestExecution chre) throws IOException {
        StopWatch stopwatch = StopWatch.createStarted();
        ClientHttpResponse response = chre.execute(hr, bytes);
        stopwatch.stop();

        LOG.info("method=" + hr.getMethod() + ", uri="+hr.getURI() + ", response_time=" + stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + ", response_code=" + response.getStatusCode().value());

        return response;
    }
}
```

And in the class where restTemplate is instanced

```
private final List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> requestInterceptors = new ArrayList<>();
requestInterceptors.add(new PerfRequestSyncInterceptor());
this.restTemplate.setInterceptors(requestInterceptors);
```

Add the Stopwatch dependency for maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>r05</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried it but it did not what was expected. Maybe it's due to changes in Spring (I did not investigate). Just want to put it here to warn others to not rely on the results when done like that.
I issued a request to a server in debug mode, so I had to press 2 times resume on the server but the interceptor measured *1ms* as time - what is simply impossible.

Comment: The same problem is faced by me dictated by @J.R. Do not use this

Answer (score 0):

> I want to measure the time of the HTTP GET request of a
>   RestTemplate.getForObject call without the the time needed for parsing
>   the response

I had the same requirements. I want to know the server response time to gauge how long it takes the server to respond without any RestTemplate response processing. I added two interceptors to the `HttpClientBuilder` with a map so I could measure the time between the low level request and response.

```
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

// Attach interceptors
ResponseTimeInterceptor interceptor = new ResponseTimeInterceptor();
httpClientBuilder.addInterceptorFirst( (HttpRequestInterceptor) interceptor );
httpClientBuilder.addInterceptorFirst( (HttpResponseInterceptor) interceptor );

// Use client with RestTemplate or on its own
HttpClient client = httpClientBuilder.build();
```

Here is the minimal dual-duty interceptor:

```
public class ResponseTimeInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor, HttpResponseInterceptor {
    private final Map<HttpContext, Long> requestMap = new MaxSizeHashMap<>( 50 );

    @Override
    public void process( HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpContext httpContext ) throws HttpException, IOException {
        requestMap.put( httpContext, System.currentTimeMillis() );
    }

    @Override
    public void process( HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext ) throws HttpException, IOException {
        long startTime = requestMap.getOrDefault( httpContext, 0L );
        long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        System.out.println( "Response time: " + diff + "ms" );
    }
}
```

After the response interceptor returns, the response data continues into the RestTemplate response handler.

Note: The `MaxSizeHashMap` is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601377.