# Hard limit/upper bound on number of keys in HashMap java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limiting the max size of a HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601333/limiting-the-max-size-of-a-hashmap-in-java)

How do you make sure HashMap in java doesn't get rehashed when number of keys exceeds capacity. I want to limit number of keys stored in hashmap (extra keys should be evicted based on default eviction policy of hashmap, but hashmap should not get rehashed/increase in capacity)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `java.util.LinkedHashMap`, usage example

```
Map m = new LinkedHashMap() {
    int max = 2;
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > max;
    }
};
m.put(1, 1);
m.put(2, 1);
m.put(3, 1);
System.out.println(m.size());
```

output

```
2
```

You can also make it LRU cache if you set `accessOrder = true` in its constructor

```
public LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any inbuilt support available for that, but you may want to implement a custom restriction yourself as:

```
    private Map<K,V> myMap = new HashMap<K,V>();
    private int MAX_SIZE = 100;

    public void addElement(K k, V v){
       if(myMap.size() == MAX_SIZE){
             throw new Exception("Size Exceeded");
             //if don't want'to throw exception then remove the above statement
       }else{
          myMap.put(k,v);
       }
    }
    ......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and provide implementation for `removeEldestEntry`

> The removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry) method may be overridden to impose a policy for removing stale mappings automatically when new mappings are added to the map.