# HashMap of an array of a certain size

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I want to create a HashMap of arrays, and I want the arrays to all be of a fixed size (8). How would I do this?

I have tried:

```
HashMap<Boolean[8],Boolean[8]> map = new HashMap<>();
```

and it seems to not work, it just wants me to delete the 8.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this C#? Add a language tag please.

Comment: It's Java. I added the tag.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight oops. its fixed now.

Comment: you can give maximum size to hashmap .you can see example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601333/limiting-the-max-size-of-a-hashmap-in-java.

Comment: If you want to use `Boolean[8]` as key, you can use `Byte` instead: Represent `true` with 1 and `false` with 0, it will do the same job.

Comment: @T.Claverie that would definitely work. Add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to use `Boolean[8]` as a type, but the correct type is `Boolean[]`. However, this will probably won't do what you expect, because the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of Java arrays are implemented using the reference.

A quick example of what it means here:

```
int[] a = new int[] {0};
int[] b = new int[] {0};

System.out.println(a.hashCode());
// 705927765 ; changes every time

System.out.println(b.hashCode());
// 366712642 ; changes every time

System.out.println(a.equals(b));
// false
```

So, if you have to use collections as keys in a HashMap, you should consider using `List`, which implement the `equals` and `hashCode` methods based on the values contained.

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new Integer(0));
b.add(new Integer(0));

System.out.println(a.hashCode());
// 31

System.out.println(b.hashCode());
// 31

System.out.println(a.equals(b));
// true
```

Now, related to your exact example, where you are trying to use arrays of `Boolean`. If the size of the arrays is bounded and inferior to 64, you can use the numeric types to represent it. Simply represent `true` with a 1 and `false`with a 0.

A reminder of the size of the Java numeric types:

- byte/Byte : 8 bits
- short/Short : 16 bits
- int/Integer : 32 bits
- long/Long : 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean[8]` is not a Parameter Type, `Boolean[]` is.