# How to maintain a LRU cache using LinkedHashMap with limited total size?

Tags: java, caching, data-structures, linkedhashmap, lru

How to maintain a cache with **limited total size**?

Let's say the limited size is 10MB, you've already used 10MB(10 * 1 MB file), now you want to add a new file with size 5MB. You need to evict the 5 least used files, but by overriding removeEldestEntry method of LinkedHashMap with "totalSize() > limit", you can only remove 1 MB file, that is, after the insertion, you will get a cache with size 14MB exceeding the limit, how can we modify the LinkedHashMap to achieve this goal?

I've searched a lot on the web, but most answers are about maintaining a cache with a **limited number of entries**.

Please comment if the question is not clear, thanks!

Comment: Well, if the `Map` holds objects of the same type, they will most-likely be of the same size.  For that reason, you would only be able to hold a limited number of entries (the exact value depending on the size of keys/values).  A `Map` is backed by two arrays and is designed to expand, so you'll want to create your own data type that rejects entries when its size exceeds a certain threshold.

Comment: You'll have to track "size" yourself.  `LinkedHashMap` doesn't really give you enough information to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I've decided to implement a class myself, thanks!

Comment: Do consider Guava/Caffeine instead, which offer this capability (`maximumWeight`).

Comment: The answer to this question is right here in the Javadoc.

Comment: @EJP Can you show me that? I've read through the doc about LinkedHashMap and find that it seems that it is not sufficient to just use that class.

Comment: Seems like you could override the `put` method to keep evicting items until the total size is below the threshold, then add your new item. In your example case, you'd call `removeEldestEntry` five times before actually adding your new item. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601333/limiting-the-max-size-of-a-hashmap-in-java for an example of overriding `put`.