# Immutable keys - fixed length map in Java

Tags: java, collections, immutability

Is there a way in Java to create a collection (map) with fixed size and length?
I.e., I would like to initialize it with K constant keys (e.g. strings) but still want to be able to change the values.

**Edit:**
The test case has a fixed number of objects, each one corresponds to a number (float). Each time a specific event in the application occurs, I would like to multiply all the numbers in the collection, except the number that corresponds to the object that "caused" the event.
The number is not logically an attribiute of the object.

Comment: and what is the specific reason for that ? can you share the background of this requirement ?

Comment: Well, you could use enums instead of strings (any maybe some mapping to get the enum for a string if that's needed). Then you could use `EnumMap`.

Comment: When you say that you want to be able to change the values, do you mean that you want to change their object type or simply their values?

Comment: @Ravi , I stumbled upon this question while trying to achieve a similar behaviour. Bascially, while trying to design a system for online debating, I created this `Debate` class, which holds a reference to a `DebateTopic` and has a private Map field for storing which `User` corresponds to which `DebatePosition` . The idea is that the `Debate` constructor accepts a reference to a `DebateTopic` and initializes the map with keys corresponding to the different `DebatePosition`s in the `DebateTopic`. This is done to prevent others from adding a position that is unrelated to the debate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you first look at [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601374/5645656) to get an idea of how to go about solving this problem, then make some changes to the code he provided so it will work in your situation:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class InstrumentedHashMap<K> extends HashMap<K, Float> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int max;

    public InstrumentedHashMap(int capacity) {
        super();
        this.max = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    public Float put(K key, Float value) {
        if (super.size() >= this.max && !super.containsKey(key)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            super.put(key, value);
            return value;
        }
    }

    public void event(K trigger, int multiplyAmount, float subtractAmount) {
        super.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
            if (!e.getKey().equals(trigger))
                e.setValue(e.getValue() * multiplyAmount);
            else
                e.setValue(e.getValue() - subtractAmount);
        });
    }
}
```

You can use the `InstrumentedHashMap#event` method to handle your "specific event", with the `multiplyAmount` parameter being the value that you want to multiply your floats by.

Comment: Amazing, just what I've needed. @cardinal, is there a way to apply a foreach with a different lambda on the key that does equals the trigger?(i.e apply two functions on different keys in the same stream)

Comment: @DsCpp sure there is, just remove the NOT operator `!` from `!e.getKey().equals(trigger)`.

Comment: In the same stream? after the filter I can't access the key that equals, it's no longer part of the stream

Comment: @DsCpp Can you give me an example of what you are trying to do? I cannot understand what it is that you want.

Comment: e.g multiply all the non-equal keys by multiplyAmount, and the key that equals sub by SubtractAmount

Comment: @DsCpp I would avoid extending `HashMap` and instead use the approach in [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601374/1441122) of implementing `Map` and having your map contain a `HashMap`. This involves implementing the `Map` interface, which has a lot of methods, so if you extend from `AbstractMap` it will save a lot of implementation work.