# Count the frequency of given words within a multiple large text files of specified directory

Tags: java

I have implemented a program to count the frequency of given words within in files of the user-specified directory. I have done this by making the directory using HashMap.I reading all files from a specified directory and then reading those files one by one. If I found the occurrences of the words then I am increasing the frequency count of that word.

**Now the restriction is that you can store max 100 pairs in HashMap**. How to do it with this restriction?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.*;

class SearchInFile
{

// This array will store the list of all files of specified directory
File[] filelist;

// This HashMap is used to store words and their frequecy
HashMap<String,Integer> worddictionary;

// Default constructor
// This will fill the files in array and will store all the words in HashMap with the frequecy 0.
public SearchInFile(String arg[])
{
    allFileList(arg[0]);
    worddictionary=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    setWords(arg);
}

//This is helper method to add words in HashMap with value 0
public void setWords(String arg[])
{
    for(int i=1;i<arg.length;i++)
    {
        worddictionary.put(arg[i],0);
    }
}

// Entry point function
// This function will accept the command line arguments from user and 
//create object of SearchInFile class which will initialize all things and 
//then it will call search() method
public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception
{
    if(arg.length<2)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid argument");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    SearchInFile obj=new SearchInFile(arg);

    if(!obj.isFilesAvailable())
    {
        System.out.println("There is no files in given directory");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    long endTime;
    long startTime;

    startTime=System.nanoTime();

    obj.search();

    endTime=System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Required time for searching is : "+ (endTime-startTime)/1000000000+" seconds");
}


// This is the helper method to check wheather there are files available or not in specified directory
public boolean isFilesAvailable()
{
    if(filelist==null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

//This method is used search the words within the files of directory
// This method will get the a file from the FileList array one by one and
// If the file is text file then it will passed to searchInFile() method
public void search() throws Exception
{   

    for(File file:filelist)
    {
        if(!getFileExtension(file).toUpperCase().equals("TXT"))
        {
            continue;
        }

        setWordCountToZero();

        searchInFile(file);
    }

}

// This method will accept the filename and will read the file line by line
// For each line it will also iterate the HashMap and will check that wheather the words are present the line or not
// If the words are present then there assocating value will increased by one for each occurance.
public void searchInFile(File file) throws Exception
{
    String buffer=null;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    while((buffer=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : worddictionary.entrySet())
        {
            if(buffer.contains(entry.getKey()))
            {
                worddictionary.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()+1);
            }
        }
    }

    displayWordCount(file.getName());
}

// This method is helper method of searchInFile() method and will be called to display frequecy of words
public void displayWordCount(String fileName)
{
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : worddictionary.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println("\nFile name : "+fileName);
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue()+" times ");
    }
}

// This method will set assocative values of all the words to 0
public void setWordCountToZero()
{
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : worddictionary.entrySet())
    {
        worddictionary.put(entry.getKey(),0);
    }
}

// This method will return extention of given file
private static String getFileExtension(File file) 
{
    String fileName = file.getName();
    if(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != -1 && fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != 0)
    {
        return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}

// This method will fill the array filelist with files of specified directory.
private void allFileList(String dirname)
{
    File dir=new File(dirname);
    if(dir==null)
    {
        return;
    }

    filelist=dir.listFiles();

    if(filelist==null)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong Directory");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting the max size of a HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601333/limiting-the-max-size-of-a-hashmap-in-java)

Comment: Regardless above comment, why do you say "restriction is that you can store max 100 pairs in HashMap", my HashMap stores 9B^2M*10T of records.

Comment: You said *"frequency of **given** words"*, which means that you already know the words you want to count, and you presumably have less than 100 of those, so fill the `Map` with those words up front, and only increment the counter while reading the text files, don't add extra words. Sorry, but I don't see what the problem is. Please *edit* the question and clarify.

Comment: @itwasntme This is an assignment. I solved it and after solving it, this restriction is given to me.

Comment: @Andreas The problem is that the number of words can be greater than 100 but the HashMap can store only 100 pairs.

Comment: @NikhilDingane Then you start with the first 100 words, scan all the files and print the counts, then take the next 100 words, re-scan the files and print the counts, and keep going until all words have been counted. --- Or get rid of such a stupid artificial restriction.

Comment: (Joking, but it has seed of truth). Fck rules, create List of 100 HashMaps, if one HashMap already has 100 words, start adding to new one, exceeds? push to third one etc.... Okkkk, the all of the 100 HashMaps have 100 words, just add another HashMap to the list, and another and another... What is the exact title/topic/theme of assignment? Do you need to procedurally/parallely process all of the files? (store the output in additional file and change it content according to your program reads)

Comment: Pointing out the ambiguously described assignment is a point for you (don't go with it to yet, firstly get full understanding).

Comment: @itwasntme Actually this assignment was given by boss. I am working as intern. I solved first part of assignment that is to count frequency count of words within the file of specified directory. When I sent it to the boss then he replied me this -

 Ok, now the restriction is that you can store max 100 words in the hashmap.

Tell me what will you do.